# How to display/show images in ascending order for a specific id using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have this piece of code that returns a set of images from database. The page works like when you click a tab, the images under that specific tab will be displayed from the database. However one set of image is displaying in descending order (Since the same was uploaded in the reverse order). I want to display that specific set of image in ascending order. The product id for that tab is '6'

Seeking your help to see if there is a work around for that.

```
function gallery() {
    $data['projs'] = $this -> spacemodel -> allProducts();
    $data['glry'] = $this -> spacemodel -> getGalleryimages();
    $data['glry_id'] = $this -> spacemodel -> getGalleryProduct_id();
    $this -> load -> view("gallery", $data);
}

function get_gallery_images() {
    $pro = $this -> input -> post("pro_id");
    //echo 'id'.$pro;
    $data['glrys'] = $this -> spacemodel -> getgallery($pro);

    foreach($data['glrys'] as $glry){
        $filtr_cat = $this -> spacemodel -> getProtitle($glry['sb11_product_id']); ?>
            <div class="portfolio app" data-cat="<?php echo $filtr_cat['product_id']; ?>" style="display:inline-block; margin:5px;">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $glry['sb11_image']; ?>" class="LightBox">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $glry['sb11_list_img']; ?>" alt="Image 2" height="150" width="150 " />
                    <span><?php echo $glry['sb11_img_title']; ?></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">$('body').LightBox()</script>

        <?php 
        }
}
```

Comment: If the data that being saved is dynamic, then this is a not a solution, since why edit the code for a dynamic data (imagine if the product id is not 6 anymore), right? I think it's best to edit the data directly

Comment: Ascending order based on what criteria? Image name, image-insert-date, image-id? Show us your function `getgallery($pro)` from where you are getting all Images.

Comment: @HastaDhana its a big list. Someone else has uploaded in the reverse order

Comment: @VirenPanchal  ascending order based on image-id